# Set theoretic image of the structure morphism of a fiber product of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a scheme.
Let $Z = X\times_S Y$ be the product of $S$-schemes.
Let $f \colon X \rightarrow S, g\colon Y \rightarrow S, h\colon Z \rightarrow S$ be the structure morphisms.
Then $h(Z) = f(X) \cap g(Y)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

Proof:
Certainly, since the map $h$ factors through both $f$ and $g$, we have an inclusion $h(Z) \subset f(X) \cap g(Y)$.  On the other hand, suppose that $s \in f(X) \cap g(Y).$    Then the fibre of $Z$ over $s$ is equal to the product of fibres $X_s$ and $Y_s$ over $\kappa(s)$.  Each of these fibres is non-empty by assumption, and hence so is there fibre product.

Here is a more concrete argument (it is just a variation on the proof that a product of non-empty schemes over a field is non-empty):
There exists $x \in X$ mapping to $s$, and also $y \in Y$ mapping to $s$, so we get maps of residue fields $\kappa(s) \hookrightarrow \kappa(x)$ and $\kappa(s) \hookrightarrow \kappa(y)$.  Now choose any maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $\kappa(x)\otimes_{\kappa(s)}\kappa(y)$, with residue field $\Omega,$ say.  Then the maps $\kappa(x), \kappa(y) \to \Omega$ induce a map Spec $\Omega \to X \times_S Y$, and the image is a point $z \in Z$ such that $h(z) = s$.  Thus we get the desired equality. QED