# Scheme theoretic image of a base change of a morphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$, $g\colon Y' \rightarrow Y$, be two morphisms of schemes.
Let $X' = X\times_Y Y'$, and let $f'\colon X' \rightarrow Y'$ be the projection.
We are interested in the relation between the *scheme theoretic* image of $f'$ and that of $f$ (in the sense of Hartshorne, exercise II, 3.11).
Namely, when does $f'(X') = g^{-1}(f(X))$ hold?

Note that the equality holds for set theoretic images (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263802/set-theoretic-image-of-a-base-change-of-a-morphism-of-schemes)), so I am asking whether (or under what conditions) the scheme structure is also preserved.

Comment: is $g^{-1}(f(X))$ a closed subscheme of $Y'$? what is its scheme structure and how is the closed embedding defined?

Answer (score 0):

Proposition 4.20 in *Algebraic Geometry I* by Görtz and Wedhorn will give you the answer. It's a valuable book in any case, I can recommend it very much.

Comment: It will take a while for me to get access to that book... Could you summarize what the answer is?

Comment: Check your email. :)